# How do you test the params hash in a Rails test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, assert, url-parameters

The following generates an error: "undefined local variable or method `params'"

`assert_equal params[:recipient_id], users(:one).id`

How do you test the params hash?

Also, how do you test `assert_redirect` when there are params present? The params are appended to the URL, so testing for `model_path` or similar fails.

Working with built in test class in Rails 3.

Comment: @B Seven: Why do you want to test what's present in the params hash? I know, that's an annoying question, but it seems odd to me that one would want to test such a thing. What's more important is that the controller is retrieving the correct object.

Comment: @Samo I am not sure if this is a valid reason, but I have a controller action that merges a time field and a date field (I have them as separate fields), and in case of error, it makes sense to ensure that the fields were properly unmerged so that they appear to the user as they were sent originally. What would be your thoughts on this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#functional-tests-for-your-controllers gives some of this information.

In this case, params is attached to the `@request` or `@response` object (depending on what HTTP method you are testing), so you can refer to it as `@request.params[:recipient_id]`.

For redirect:
`assert_redirected_to post_path(assigns(:post))` will assert that you are redirected to the proper path for a given model. The assigns method should have the instance variables you are setting inside of the controller to pass to the view