# RSpec: Test that a model receives #create with certain parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I just ran into an edge case where I was calling:

```
Model.create(param: derp, param2: derp2, ...)
```

and one of the params I was passing in was wrong.

I want to test that a model is receiving call with the right parameters being passed in.

My instinct was to do:

```
expect_any_instance_of(Model).to receive(:create).with(param: derp, param2: derp2, ...)
```

But that gives:

```
Model does not implement #create
```

Most of the things I am passing in are just model attributes, and I can just test that they were passed in correctly like this:

```
it "passes the derp into param" do
    expect(Model.first.param).to eq(derp)
end
```

However, one of the things I am passing in is an attr_accessor, and the model is doing stuff with an after_create callback (this was actually the param that I was passing in wrong, so out of principal, the whole test was really meant for that).

I can test it like above...query it, make sure that the after create did its thing, which meant it was passing in correctly - but then I'm coupling in that after create functionality when I really just want to test to make sure that the model received the right params when I called create, regardless of what happens after in the callback.

I'm definitely being picky here, but I want my unit tests to be as modular as possible and not rely on other code. I just want to make sure that when I call create, it receives the data that it is supposed to receive.

The only thing I can find in the RSpec docs is

```
expect(Model.count).to eq(1)
```

Any ideas here?

EDIT: Thanks all...all 3 are correct. Accepted the first one :) This is pretty simple, can't believe I missed it. I actually tried that at first but had a bang (!) on it and that was causing it to fail... needed to do receive(:create!).

Comment: I'm assuming that if passed the wrong params, the Model won't be created and you want to ensure that's the case?

Comment: In this case, no. The model could still be created...the one param that was not being passed in correctly (the attr_accessor) was not required.

Comment: Perhaps this would be useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628021/how-do-you-test-the-params-hash-in-a-rails-test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the core of your question, but there's a conceptual error here:

```
expect_any_instance_of(Model).to receive(:create).with(param: derp, param2: derp2, ...)
```

The receiver of the `#create` method is the `class` `Model`, not any of it's instances. The following should work perfectly fine:

```
expect(Model).to receive(:create).with(args ...)
```

As a general rule, you should avoid expect/allow_any_instance_of, as it often indicates you could improve your design.

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

This won't work...

`expect_any_instance_of(Model).to receive(:create).with(param: derp, param2: derp2, ...`)

because `create` is not an instance method `#create`, it's a model method `.create`

You could try

```
expect(Model).to receive(:create).with(param: derp, param2: derp2, ...)
```

The `Model.count` example just confirms that the record was created and as you say in your comment, the record could be created regardless of valid parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `expect_any_instance_of(Model)` but create is a class function, you can use:

```
expect(Model).to have_received(:create).with(param: derp, param2: derp2, ...)
```